# QUERY function with Count

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this data from a sheet1 where I need to just show up in sheet2 col `A,B,C,D,E,F` and the latest date from col `F` and the value of that row from col `E` then add a column for charges to count items from Sheet1.

How can I pull that using QUERY? I will apply it to a 3k+ data. So the output is not limited to just 3.

Sharing the file for what needs for the output:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NbA7tInyoYTYPPqj6yKbAMdSpzaOpY0Vlj-gM7du_Nk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please show what you tried as well and/or a brief descriptio of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Comment: Questions should be self contained. While external links are welcome, consider adding a ascii table or screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) to accomplish your goal:

```
=query(Sheet1!$A$1:$F,"Select A,B,C,D,MIN(E),MAX(F),count(E)-1 WHERE A IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A,B,C,D ORDER BY A desc")
```

[image: EXAMPLE]

Answer (score 0):

In a new tab in cell A1 try

```
=query(ArrayFormula(vlookup(unique(Sheet1!A2:A&Sheet1!B2:B&Sheet1!C2:C&Sheet1!D2:D), sort({Sheet1!A2:A&Sheet1!B2:B&Sheet1!C2:C&Sheet1!D2:D, Sheet1!A2:F, countif(Sheet1!A2:A&Sheet1!B2:B&Sheet1!C2:C&Sheet1!D2:D, Sheet1!A2:A&Sheet1!B2:B&Sheet1!C2:C&Sheet1!D2:D)-1}, 7, 0), {2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, 0)), "where Col1 <>''")
```

and see if that works?

[image]